# How can an exhaustive when throw NoWhenBranchMatchedException?

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-interop, kotlin-null-safety, kotlin-java-interop

I observe a LiveData with an exhaustive `when` statement, how can it throw a `NoWhenBranchMatchedException` at runtime? Wasn't exhaustiveness checked for at compile time?

```kotlin
enum class MyEnum { Foo, Bar }

liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { enumInstance ->
  val instance: MyEnum = when (enumInstance) {
    is Foo -> {}
    is Bar -> {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why it can happen

Because LiveData is an API written in Java, and any type can be null in Java, Kotlin's null-safety is not enforced at compile time. The IntelliJ IDEs refer to these types with a `!` suffix:

> `T!` means "`T` or `T?`" ([source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types))

`enumInstance` may be `null`, but Kotlin doesn't do any null checks on it because `Observer` is a Java interface. That's why this `when` statement is still considered to be exhaustive by the compiler, even though it isn't.  Setting the value of the LiveData from the example to null will cause a `NoWhenBranchMatchedException` to be thrown at runtime.

```kotlin
liveData.value = Foo // Perfectly safe at runtime
liveData.value = null // NOT safe at runtime
liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { enumInstance ->
  // enumInstance is "MyEnum!" (nullability unknown to Kotlin)
  val instance = when (enumInstance) {
    is Foo -> {}
    is Bar -> {}
  }
})
```

> Any reference in Java may be null, which makes Kotlin's requirements of strict null-safety impractical for objects coming from Java. Types of Java declarations are treated in Kotlin in a specific manner and called platform types. Null-checks are relaxed for such types, so that safety guarantees for them are the same as in Java [...] ([source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types))

## What you can do to prevent it

### With compile-time safety

If it comes from Java, either check for null or assume it to be nullable at any time. Make the type explicit to Kotlin.

What we were doing:

```kotlin
val unknownNullability = javaApi.getString() // "String!"
unknownNullability.split(',') // Runtime error
```

What we should do:

```kotlin
val knownToBeNullable: String? = javaApi.getString()
knownToBeNullable.split(',') // Compile-time error
```

Fixing the example code:

```kotlin
liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { enumInstance: MyEnum? ->
  // Now I know I may receive null
  // This will fail at compile-time:
  when (enumInstance) {
    is Foo -> {}
    is Bar -> {}
    // null case is required now
  }
})
```

### Without compile-time safety

You can simply avoid using `null` with `LiveData` (and other places with Java interop). Observers won't receive null unless you post it.

```kotlin
liveData.value = Foo
liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { enumInstance ->
  // I'm sure I won't receive null
})
```

However, code changes constantly. Even though your code today never posts `null`, it may come to post it one day, and with this approach any nullability errors will only come up at runtime.